# Why this behaviour of Node.js + MongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, benchmarking, mean-stack

These are the benchmark report of simple Node.js server and single MongoDB instance(no sharding) connected via native driver. Both Node server and MongoDB are on same machine. Benchmarking done on AWS instances. These are load testing results were each user thread makes continuous requests for 300 secs. Testing is done by Jmeter on M4.xlarge machine so that there is no client bottleneck. Node server fetches 3 document from mongo and respond in JSON format. There is only one collection with 10 documents(very small size texts) in mongodb database. Can anyone explain that why at starting (upto 250 user threads) every machine gives same throughput and average response time irrespective of AWS instance configuration?
MongoDB version 3.0 Node.js 0.12
[image][image][image]